# How can I rename a core created in Solr?

Tags: solr, rename

I must create some indexes using Solr.
I have created a lot of cores with `bin/solr create` command:

```
bin/solr create -c core_name
```

After that, I added some documents using `bin/post` command:

```
bin/post -c core_name /documents_path/
```

Now I must rename some cores to make some tests but I don't know how I can do it.

I cannot simply delete the core and re-add the core with the correct name, because add a lot of documents takes a long time.

How can I rename the cores using command line commands as in the operations creation and addition of the documents??

Thank you!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [CoreAdminHandler (which is available by default in 5.x)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API) is the preferred external interface for making changes to cores.

To [rename a core](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-RENAME), issue a RENAME command:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RENAME&core=oldname&other=newname
```

Comment: But now I have a problem with post command, in fact, when I use this command to add a lot of documents I have this error: ./post: argument list too long. Someone can I help me? Thank you!

Comment: Create a new question with the details of your current problem. But that sounds like an error message coming from bash - and not from the tool itself. Limit the number of documents in each ./post command to the amount supported in your shell. You can do this by using 'find' or a different tool (search on Google for "argument list too long" and you'll find many ideas on how to get around the limitation).